# Deleting pointer array crashes caller's application

Tags: c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2013, dllimport, assertion

DLL: Visual Studio 2013(VC12) / App: Visual Studio 2010(VC10)

I am creating a library that allows a client access to our system. However it appears that when deleting an array of pointers returned from the dll then the client application crashes. When deleting a normal pointer (non array) everything seems to work fine. Ideas? I noticed that when using VC12 as the client application the array is deleted OK, although when using VC10 I get the crash.

So my question: Why does the client app crash when deleting the pointer array when returned from the dll, if there was an issue deleting memory allocated by the dll wouldn't the delete system; be an issue as well?

```
struct IDevice {
    virtual ~IDevice() {}
    char name[64];
};

class Device : public IDevice {
public:
    Device() {}
    ~Device() {}
};

struct ISystem {
    virtual ~IDevice() {}
    virtual Result::Value GetDevices(Collection<IDevice**>* deviceCollection) = 0;
};

class System : public ISystem {
public:
    Result::Value GetDevices(Collection<IDevice**>* deviceCollection) {
        Result::Value result = Result::Success;
        deviceCollection->collectionSize = 1;
        deviceCollection->collection = new IDevice*[1];

        IDevice* device = new Device();
        Utilities::strcpy_safe(device->name, "blackey");
        deviceCollection->collection[0] = device;
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Collection {
    T collection;
    int collectionSize;
};

///////// Main App ///////////

LoginInfo loginInfo;
string ip("192.168.1.2");
string u("admin");
string password("admin");
loginInfo.port = 443;
loginInfo.ssl = true;
strncpy_s(loginInfo.ipAddress, ip.c_str(), sizeof(loginInfo.ipAddress)-1);
strncpy_s(loginInfo.uname, u.c_str(), sizeof(loginInfo.uname)-1);
strncpy_s(loginInfo.password, password.c_str(), sizeof(loginInfo.password)-1);

ISystem* system = nullptr;
// SystemLogin calls into my dll which allocates memory for system OK
Result::Value result = SystemLogin(&loginInfo, &system);

Collection<IDevice**> devices;
// If the line below is uncommented, and the dll is modified to not allocate memory, but instead use this memory
// then below the delete[] devices.collection; works.
//devices.collection = new IDevice*[50];

// Makes a call into the library which populates devices
result = system->GetDevices(&devices);

for (int i = 0; i < devices.collectionSize; i++) {
    // Each item in the array is deleted OK
    delete devices.collection[i];
}

// Deleting this array of pointers crashes (see screenshots) when it's memory was allocated in the dll.
delete[] devices.collection;

// system deletes OK
delete system;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You did not show enough code. How about a [mcve]. Include both the allocation and the deallocation.

Comment: Also you cannot "delete" something created with malloc (in case you did that)

Comment: More code added. Let me know if anything else would help.

Comment: _"if there was an issue deleting memory allocated by the dll wouldn't the delete system; be an issue as well?"_ Not necessarily, `delete[]` does more work than just `delete` and so if the runtime that allocated it is not the same as the runtime that deallocates it (which I believe can happen across DLL boundaries) then the `delete[]` may not be able to find the magic metadata that says how many elements the array has, or whatever else might be needed by the `delete[]`

Comment: [*I've read a lot about how it would be better to allocate/deallocate either in the client or the dll although for as many objects that are being returned I don't want to create a million Free() methods.*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479227/deleting-pointer-array-crashes-callers-application#comment52820663_32479706) So you know that you are doing it wrong, but you plugged on regardless? And then when the expected failure occurred you wonder why it occurred? Am I reading this right?

Comment: I'm surprised that even-though I singled out my direct question above in in the 'So my question' paragraph the only technical answer has been from @JonathanWakely explaining why a delete[] may be different than delete;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if client application and your dll is compiled using the same settings. To prevent such problems its better to either:

1. Allocate/deallocate memory on client side
2. Allocate/deallocate memory on dll (server) side

I would recomend #1, but I see you are using #2. So what you should do now is to add `system->FreeDevices(&devices);` which will deallocate memory - but inside your `dll`.

[edit]

Reference to read from msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx

the important part is about different CRTs with which dll and client application might be build. This might cause the exact problems you experience:

> Also, because each copy of the CRT library has its own heap manager, allocating memory in one CRT library and passing the pointer across a DLL boundary to be freed by a different copy of the CRT library is a potential cause for heap corruption.

Comment: I've read a lot about how it would be better to allocate/deallocate either in the client or the dll although for as many objects that are being returned I don't want to create a million Free() methods.

Comment: @Blackey I have added some references, I am afraid you dont have much choice but to write those million Free() methods. At least this is what most APIs does.

Comment: @Blackey you could also add a callback to your DLL which would have to be provided by client code, it would be responsible for allocating memory. This callback would be used inside your dll for memory that is returned to client - which would be then freed by client code.

Comment: Alternatively I could probably pass in Collection where the collectionSize is 0, then have the method set the size to the proper amount and respond with a result of SizeNotBigEnough and then with that return code the caller will know what size to make the array. I was hoping to avoid this, but I guess I cant. Strange though that I can allocate in the dll for a normal pointer, it's just this array of pointers that is the headache.

Comment: @Blackey creating a million "Free()" on the DLL where you know its safe is better than letting the client guess wich Free he needs  and manually writing code each time

Answer (score 0):

Note that in general it is better that stuff created from 1 DLL must be created and deleted by the DLL (just a better design, if you want to avoid to call custom deleters then you have to pass your own allocator to the DLL wich call "new" son you can just call "delete" on returned objects.).

However, the code you posted cannot help reproduce the problem becase we don't see how the object is created within the DLL, so we can't really help.

However since the intent seems to use a pointer to pointer (pretty bad, what about a `std::vector< std::unique_ptr< IDevice> >`? wich has the same performance and allow to write less code).

I assume you did the following inside your `GetDevices` call

```
typdef IDevice * IDevicePtr;
//using IDevicePtr = IDevice *;
void GetDevices( Collection<IDevicePtr*> * devices)
{
    devices->collectionSize = 10;
    devices->collection = new IDevicePtr[10];
    for(int i =0; i<10;i++)
        devices->collection[i] = new CDevice();
}
```

In that case the code you are using for deleting is ok, and the error is something else.

Note that

- `IDevice` must have virtual destructor implemented
- `ISystem` must have virtual destructor implemented

Comment: The reason I'm staying away from stl classes is I know they break between different versions of Visual Studio so I'm trying not to pass stl objects across dll borders. Also I would like the code to be compatible with VC10 which doesn't offer full C++11 support.

Comment: @Blackey: The STL is not special. All classes are risky across DLL boundaries when different parts are built with different compilers. This is due to a lack of a standard C++ ABI, even across MSVC++ versions. To be safe, stick with one compiler _or_ use only C types in the interface and handle allocation plus deallocation in the same DLL.

Comment: Each compiler version should have its own DLL @Blackey .So don't be afraid of stuff breaking stuff, it will break anyway. If you want to make a "uninversal" (it won't be universal of course) binary you should wrap it with C interface using the C name mangling and calling convention, so forget about passing template parameters to functions, I fear it is much more maintanable building X different DLLS for each compiler version instead of wrapping all in a C interface.